# htaccess: specific directory requests to forward to PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, thumbnails

So I am writing an on-the-fly thumbnail generator for a CMS and I am trying to find the best way to handle requests. Specifically, I need to come up with the apache code for an htaccess file that will take all requests to a thumbnail folder and send them to a thumbnail.php file instead.

Ideally it would *only* forward you to thumbnail.php if the thumbnail doesn't exist, although checking for file existence within apache is beyond me.

The request URL would look like this:

http://unknown_domain.com/unknown_folder/media/thumbnails/image-name.jpg?w=200&h=100&c=true

And images would be stored in the thumbnails something like this (or could be the same URL as below if that makes more sense):

http://unknown_domain.com/unknown_folder/media/thumbnails/image-name-200-100-true.jpg

Here is the closest I've come so far, I assume I put this htaccess in the thumbnails folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /unknown_folder/media/thumbnails/ # optional, depends on your setup

#Check for file existence here and forward if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-])-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-true.jpg$ thumbnail.php?w=$2&h=$2&c=true [LQSE]
```

Thank you for any help provided in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? What behavior, exactly, are you expecting? What behavior are you actually seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for a regex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /unknown_folder/media/thumbnails/ # optional, depends on your setup

#Check for file existence here and forward if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-true\.jpg$ thumbnail.php?w=$2&h=$3&c=true [L,QSA]
```

I have not tested it, but ideally a request to

```
/unknown_folder/media/thumbnails/bla-you-name-of-whatever-200-100-true.jpg
```

should call the script `thumbnail.php` with it's parameters.

**Edited:** Fixed some typos and errors.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, it gives an Internal Server Error (500) when I attempt to access an image:  `http://getdirectus.com/dev/media/thumbnails/test-200-100-true.jpg`

Comment: I think it's the .htaccess file. Check the error log of your webserver, it should say which line has an error. Regex errors are displayed as well.

Comment: dot `.` needs to be escaped as `\.` and flags should be `[L,QSA]` in the end.

Comment: I had some errors in the .htaccess demo, updated. If you still have 500'ers please check your error log as I can not complete mimic your system.

Comment: @anubhava That's exactly what it was, but also the `[a-z-]` only matches a single lowercase letter, what is the best way to have it get any file name before the `-200-100-true.jpg`?

Comment: @cbh: I corrected `[a-z-]+` with a plus, it was one of the errors and slipped through. What does "any filename" stand for? For what specific are you looking? Some certain characters? If so, which ones? Or is it the ending at the end (.jpg, .png etc.)?

Comment: @hakre Actually that change you just made resolved the issue. I think I have enough now to adapt. I will allow it to handle uppercase file names and other possible filename characters. As well as having the final `-true` to be a variable allowing `true|false`.

Comment: @hakre Would you perchance know how to make that last `-([true|false])` optional within the URL? Would that be done with two RewriteRules?

Comment: @hakre So sorry for the barrage of comments, but I think a cleaner URL would be an optional `-crop` at the end of the file name: `test-file-200-100-crop.jpg` or `test-file-200-100.jpg`

Comment: try: `(-(true|false))?`, should be $5 then but not always available as being optional. But if possible I would stick with one rule instead of two.

Comment: @cbh: That's the resource I go to when I need help since years: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html - sometimes I must re-read a lot but I ever found the answers to my questions there . And not to forget: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @hakre Perfect, I ended up using `(-(crop))` which seems to work. If this works on my server should it work on all/most servers that allow for htaccess? Thanks for the resources, bookmarked!

Comment: Rewrite rules can be depended to the directory layout on a specific server and the apache version. I test my last version on apache 1.3 which works quite well than on servers with a higher version. The rest is try and error :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is here, but there are a few more filters you should be using to check for file existence...

```
RewriteEngine on

#Check for file existence here and forward if exists
RewriteCond ^/(regex_here)/$ !-f
RewriteCond ^/(regex_here)/$ !-d
RewriteCond ^/(regex_here)/$ !-s
RewriteCond ^/(regex_here)/$ !-l

RewriteRule ^/(regex_here)/$ /thumbnail.php?w=$1&h=$2&c=$3
```